# 作成したアプリをiPadのシミュレータで動作させると、iPhoneサイズで表示される

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, dart

Flutterでモバイルアプリを開発中です。
作成したアプリをiPadシミュレータで実行すると、iPhoneサイズで表示されます。
右下に拡大マークが表示されており、それをクリックするとサイズは大きくなるのですが、縦横比はiPhoneアプリのサイズのままで拡大されてしまい、空白の部分は黒くなっています。
デバイスの画面いっぱいフルサイズで表示されるよう実装しているつもりなのですが、問題がある点のご指摘をいただきたいです。

・環境
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
XCode v13.1
macOS 11.4
Apple M1チップ
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MainMenu());
}

class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  MainMenu();

  @override
  _MainMenu createState() => _MainMenu();
}

class _MainMenu extends State<MainMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home()
    );
  }
}


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home>{
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      height:double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('title'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          //略
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

このサイトを見ました
https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/c133xz/flutter_ipados/

こう言っています：グーグルがこのリポジトリにサンプルを作っていました。

https://github.com/2d-inc/developer_quest

そのコードを見たり実行したりヒントが出るかもしれません、ここまでしかわからないので宜しくおねがいします。

以上